# Настройка Apache как в Denver

Tags: php, веб-программирование, apache, веб-сервер, wamp-server

Кто поделиться мудростью как настроить например WampServer чтобы он создавал виртуальные хосты как в Denver'e.
А именно сканировал корневую папку www, создавал виртуальные хосты, и саб-доммена для них исходя и вложенных папок, например:

```
/www/test.ru/first/index.php
/www/test.ru/www/index.php
/www/localhost/www/index.php
...
```

То создались бы:

```
http://first.test.ru/index.php
http://www.test.ru/index.php
http://test.ru/index.php
http://www.localhost/index.php
http://localhost/index.php
```

Или хотя бы чтобы просто, без саб-домменов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно подключить модуль `mod_vhost_alias`

В виртуальном хосте указать IP и директиву, например так

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAlias *.local
    ServerAlias *.test
    # перечисляем DNS, на который будет отзываться виртуальный хост
    # чтобы охватить побольше пользуемся *
    VirtualDocumentRoot /www/%1

    <Directory /www>
    # добавить нужное
    </Directory>

    # добавить нужное    
</VirtualHost>
```

, где %1 - домен первого уровня

Таких виртуальных хостов придется делать несколько если некоторые домены будут отличаться вторым уровнем домена или несколькими сразу

См. также

- [Массовый хостинг с помощью mod_vhost_alias](http://www.softtime.ru/info/apache.php?id_article=103)
- [Документация на английском языке](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html)